# Клик только один раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

К примеру,есть обработчик

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
$('body').append("<div class='test'></div>");
})
```

Как разрешить выполнение только 1 раз?

Comment: $('#btn1').one('click', function() {});

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Используйте метод [`.one()`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9) для этого:

```js
$("#btn1").one('click', function(){
  $('body').append("<div class='test'>Something</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='btn1' value='Click me!' />
```

Comment: а если без jQuery?

Comment: А что без жиквери? Навешиваем не саму пользовательскую функцию, а обёртку, которая после срабатывания удаляет себя методом `removeEventListener` и запускает саму функцию.

Comment: понял вопросов нет спасибо :)